# Get separate user, system, etc CPU usage per process

Tags: top, cpu-usage

On a Unix or Unix-like system, how do I view the percent CPU usage per process, split into user and system and other time categories? `top` shows me overall "sy", "us", "wa", etc for the entire computer or per core, but I don't see anything in the manual showing how to show those stats per process.

To illustrate...
top shows something like this:

```
top - 18:11:58 up 9 days,  6:41, 17 users,  load average: 2.42, 2.38, 2.47
Tasks: 2642 total,   4 running, 2638 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.9 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  26413387+total, 26355763+used,   576240 free,   233544 buffers
KiB Swap:  8921084 total,  8920140 used,      944 free. 14931166+cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
63209 postgres  20   0  0.101t 0.012t 0.012t R 100.0  5.0 389:44.92 postgres
62356 postgres  20   0  0.101t 922336 886508 R 100.0  0.3  10:25.82 postgres
 2139 rabbitmq  20   0 9817.9m 5.334g   2968 S  10.4  2.1   1848:43 beam.
```

For example, I'd like to see something like this (see %CPU(sy) and %CPU(us)):

```
top - 18:11:58 up 9 days,  6:41, 17 users,  load average: 2.42, 2.38, 2.47
Tasks: 2642 total,   4 running, 2638 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.9 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  26413387+total, 26355763+used,   576240 free,   233544 buffers
KiB Swap:  8921084 total,  8920140 used,      944 free. 14931166+cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU(us) %CPU(sy) %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
63209 postgres  20   0  0.101t 0.012t 0.012t R   100.0    1.0      5.0 389:44.92 postgres
62356 postgres  20   0  0.101t 922336 886508 R   100.0    0.4      0.3  10:25.82 postgres
 2139 rabbitmq  20   0 9817.9m 5.334g   2968 S    10.4    0.2      2.1   1848:43 beam.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can have the statistics you want about a process by using this Command:

```
pidstat -u -p <PID>
```

for example

```
pidstat -u -p 2345
```

Comment: Yep, that works. I had to do `pidstat -u -p <PID>` on my system, but it probably depends on what version of the utility you have.

Comment: it's a great utility you can have an average value in the time for example :

Comment: `pidstat -u -p <PID> 25`

this will give you the avarage of CPU consemption by the process in 25 seconds